# Derive a AES-KW key in JS

Tags: javascript, aes

I try to derive a AES-KW key in js like:

```js
let { publicKey: pub, privateKey: key } = 
  await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    { name: 'ECDH', namedCurve: 'P-521' },
    true,
    ['deriveKey'],
  )

await crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
  { name: 'ECDH', public: pub },
  key,
  { name: 'AES-KW', length: 256 },
  false,
  ["encrypt", "decrypt"],
)
```

with error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.

I don't know why, because AES-GCM can succeed.

Comment: [Practical disadvantages of GCM mode encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10775/practical-disadvantages-of-gcm-mode-encryption)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, [`crypto.subtle.deriveKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveKey) with `name: 'AES-KW'` as `derivedKeyAlgorithm` provides a key which can be used for *wrapping* another key according to [RFC 3394](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3394), see also [`AES-KW`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/wrapKey#AES-KW). For this `['wrapKey', 'unwrapKey']` has to be used as `keyUsages` instead of `['encrypt', 'decrypt']`, see also this [example (`getKey`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/wrapKey#Examples).

With `name: 'AES-GCM'` as `derivedKeyAlgorithm` and `['encrypt', 'decrypt']` as `keyUsages` a key is provided which can be used for *encryption and decryption* with AES-GCM.

Example for `AES-KW`:

```js
crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    { name: 'ECDH', namedCurve: 'P-521' }, 
    true, 
    ['deriveKey']
    ).then(function(keypair){
        crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
            { name: 'ECDH', public: keypair.publicKey },  // In practice, this is the public key of the recipient
            keypair.privateKey,                           // In practice, this is the own private key
            { name: 'AES-KW', length: 256 },
            true,
            ["wrapKey", "unwrapKey"],
        ).then(function(wrappingKey){
            console.log(wrappingKey);
        })
    })
```